# how to change the present url to move to its original url after a form is submitted through an iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Well.. the title was not pretty clear to make you understand but couldn't think what to write. So here is the case..

I loaded a client site (say, www.aaa.com) within my site (www.mysite.com) through an iFrame. Now there is a form in the client site and when it is submitted or any action button is pressed, I want to go directly to the main url in my browser rather than everything loading in my site within the iFrame.

Currently, when I submit the form in the iFrame, though the page changes but everything happens on www.mysite.com but I want this to go to www.aaa.com

Any help will be appreciated deeply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you show the code in which triggers the redirecting?
can't you just specify it? there are many ways to do this 
in php that would be a

```
    header('location:http://www.aaa.com'); //php
```